# IE11 uses first select option as a placeholder rather than blank select

Tags: html, angular, browser, internet-explorer-11

I came across a bug where IE11 decides to put a 'placeholder' on a mandatory select if the model's variable value doesn't exist.

Say select value = `vm.model.name` and it doesn't exist just yet because it hasn't been selected, IE11 would put first option of that select as a 'placeholder'.
This is an example of what I mean: https://angular-select-ie-bug.stackblitz.io/
Try running it in IE11 (issue doesn't exist in IE10) and compare it to Chrome for example.

This tricks you into thinking you've got an option selected automatically for you whereas model value still doesn't exist... It's just this pointless placeholder.

I've found out in this thread: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/14505
that the guy fixed it in his pull request but it's still pending.

My question is whether there's a way to implement his solution to my angular library before his pull request is merged? I want to be able to use that change.

Or maybe there's a better solution where I don't have to add a blank option at the top of my list to fix it.